# Extjs Access grid's store params

Tags: extjs, parameters, grid, store

Is there anyway to access a grid's store params within the ExtJS code?

I have only been able to access them is in a REST call.

They are loaded using:

```
monthStore.load({params: {id:id, month: month}});
```

Comment: As mentioned by you - "access a grid's store params within the ExtJS code?" Could you elaborate a bit more that where exactly in the code you want to exact the parameters and what actions you want to perform on them?

Comment: I basically just want to get the value of the month parameter out in a renderer function to be able to use that value

Answer (score 0):

Had this 'month' been in the extraParams, then you could have accessed it the following way:

```
storeVar.proxy.extraParams.month
```

Where storeVar is the instance of your grid store.

But to access the params, I shall suggest you to put it up in some global variable, or may be in the same scope where the renderer is so that this variable can be accessed.

Hope this helps.